# I need to go over an ndarray and return the bool value of each cell (as an ndarray), if it is divisible by a given X within one line

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

sorry for broken English.
I tried this but it didn't work,
I think I need to go over the vector but I don't know how to do this in one line

```
def ModBooleanVector(inputVector, X):

     return  np.array(inputVector() % X == 0)
```

Comment: what is `inputVector`? is it a function? try `np.array(inputVector()) % X == 0` if its not a function do `np.array(inputVector) % X == 0` instead

Comment: thanks for help i should have used [:] instead of ()                                                         return  np.array((inputVector[:] % X) == 0)

Comment: `return inputVector % X == 0` will work

Comment: @NadavGvili if`np.array((inputVector[:] % X) == 0)` works, that means that inputVector is already a numpy array, you can simplify it like this `return inputVector % X == 0`

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. Could you provide the error message and a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?